# I've never seen 'class __proxy__' before, what does this mean(I only have seen that like def __str__)

Tags: python, django

this code is in the django.utils.functional.py

```
class __proxy__(Promise):
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Magic names", ones that start and end with double underscores, are reserved for the language in Python (but the compiler does not enforce that rule at present); Django is violating that rule, or setting itself up as "being the language" -- not a terrible sin, but an unpleasant practice.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a name. And because it starts with `_` it's meant to be private to that module.

Why they chose that name? You'll have to ask the developers.